# What is causing these memory leaks?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I've nailed the culprit of my memory leak down to the rendering of text, and don't understand why every 2 seconds the amount of physical memory the program is using goes up by about 0.02 GB. Could you help?

```
#include "Text.h"


CText::CText()
{
    TTF_Init();
}


CText::~CText()
{
    free(mfont);
        free(message);
    free(tex);
}

void CText::Draw(std::string font, int size, std::string m_text, SDL_Renderer* renderer, int x, int y, SDL_Color color)
{
    int w = 0;
    int h = 0;

    mfont = TTF_OpenFont(("res/" + font + ".ttf").c_str(), size);
    message = TTF_RenderText_Solid(mfont, m_text.c_str(), color);
    tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, message);
    SDL_QueryTexture(tex, NULL, NULL, &w, &h);
    textRect.x = x;
    textRect.y = y;
    textRect.w = w;
    textRect.h = h;

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, tex, NULL, &textRect);

    TTF_CloseFont(mfont);
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: I don't think you should recreate `mfont` every time your window update.

Comment: The class is created outside a while loop and Draw is called on it within the game loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time you call `Draw`, you create a new texture in `tex` without freeing the previous one.

Your destructor is also wrong... `free` is only for memory allocated with `malloc` (or `calloc` or `realloc`). As you are not using `malloc` anywhere, you really have no business using `free`.

- I don't think `mfont` is valid at this point (you're freeing it in `Draw()`.
- `tex` should be freed with [`SDL_DestroyTexture`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DestroyTexture).
- `message` also should be freed by [`SDL_FreeSurface`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FreeSurface).

I think the short answer is that you just need to read, understand, and follow the documentation for the APIs you are trying to use.

Comment: "free is only for memory allocated with malloc" can one not do free(new int); ?

Comment: You should generally never use malloc/free with C++ ( unless you have a very specific reason )And let SDL handle the free'ing of SDL objects.

Comment: @phyrrus9 no, match malloc/free or new/delete do not mix the 2 up.

Comment: @gbjbaanb I almost always use straight C, and never use new anyways, i was just curious

Comment: often new will call malloc under the covers (just like cout will call printf) but you cannot be sure, so follow the documentation.

Comment: @phyrrus9: One important difference between `free` and `delete` is, that `delete` will call a class instances destructor. `free` just frees the memory.